# Fabic.js grouped items are offset

Tags: fabricjs

So, I'm pretty much trying to just select a couple of objects by selecting them and activating a grouping function. So far, everything works right, If I move the grouped items, they move correctly, but the moment I release focus on the group, it gets offsets.

The objects are in one part of the canvas and the selectable area is in another. I already tried `setCords()` after the group is added and rendered, but no luck

You can see the issue in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJLopez/2u5xadn4/1/), just select the 2 squares with the mouse and press the "Create Group" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `setActiveGroup` method. There are two ways you can fix it:

1. Just try removing `setActiveGroup` if you don't need newly formed group to be selected and it will work as expected.
2. Use `setActiveObject` instead of `setActiveGroup` to set group as active. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3z19qj11/

This seems to be a bug with `setActiveGroup` method. I tried this with the latest version of fabric.js (1.4.13) because lot of group related bugs are fixed in each version, but this seems to be broken in latest version as well.

Comment: You gotta be kidding me, a single line had me stuck for the weekend!! Jajajaja, I feel like a fook

Thank you very much!

And yes, I should be using setActiveObject, instead of setActiveGroup, it's no longer a Group, but a Object that it's a group